# virtio network interface stops after wake

Tags: virtualbox, virtio

I'm running vagrant with the Virtualbox provider on my laptop and use the virtio network interface to mitigate super slow DNS lookups with the standard network device used by Virtualbox.

Now putting my laptop to sleep and waking it up later, I can't use the virtio network interface. Running an vagrant reload to restart the virtualbox solves the problem, but is of course something I would like to avaid. vagrant uses an additional network device with the standard setup to do it's work.

Does anybody know how to wake up virtio? Linux distribution is Arch Linux, btw.